# JDBC Connection to Oracle database using TLS Certificate

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to write a connection class in Java to connect to an Oracle database using the JDBC driver, but I want to secure the parameters like jdbcurl/username/password which is used to connect to the Oracle database.

I have to use TLS certificate concept to connect to the Oracle database in Java. I tried looking for a working example but couldn't find one.

Can anyone give me an idea how to implement that. I have to add connection pooling concept also to it.

Answer (score 7):

Refer to the whitepaper linked below for details.

> the JDBC URL must use the *tcps* protocol in order to activate SSL in the JDBC Thin driver.
>
> For example the following URL activates SSL:
>
> ```
> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=servername
>      )(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))
> ```

This answer assumes that you have already configured TLS correctly on the oracle server. If not, refer to the [SSL With Oracle JDBC Thin Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) whitepaper.

This whitepaper also includes more advanced options like authentication, selection of cipher, etc.