# JDBC connect to Oracle database with SSL

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, jdbc

I've configured a standard database connection, I connect to an Oracle database.
The database will be configured to use SSL, this means that I'll need to specify the server certificate in order to connect.

The SSL itself is with **SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE** and configured a Oracle Wallet.

Can it be done using JDBC?

This is my current code:

```
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.200.96:1521:NNVSDB", "VSU22","VSU22");
```

Comment: Might wanna take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/sslthin.htm#BABJIHFJ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415733/jdbc-connection-to-oracle-database-using-tls-certificate (not voting to close, as that question + my answer are 4 years old, and I'm not sure if things have changed/improved since then).

Comment: were you able to figure outthe configuration?

Answer (score 6):

You can find a pdf with some documentation here :
[SSL With Oracle JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf), you have some code example page 11 and 12:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=servername)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))"); 
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.setProperty("user", "scott"); 
props.setProperty("password", "tiger"); 
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", 
                  "/truststore/ewallet.p12"); 
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","PKCS12"); 
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","welcome123"); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Comment: I saw this example, but I use a Wallet not a truststore.

Comment: Yeap, you have two type of Wallet :
SSO and PKCS12, you can either set property for SSO, where you don't even need password  
    `props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/truststore/cwallet.sso");  
     props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","SSO");`

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev Could you please post the listener,sqlnet & tnsnames.ora, I am attempting to configure the jdbc with ssl using oracle wallets but failing to do so