# How to specify Trust store and trust store type for Spark JDBC connection

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, truststore, spark-jdbc

I am new to Spark and we are currently using the spark-java to create orc files from Oracle database. I was able to configure the connection with

```
sqlContext.read().jdbc(url,table,props)
```

However, I couldn't find any way in the properties to specify the trustStore or trustStoreType. Can someone help me about how to specify these properties?

I already tried populating the properties as

```
 props.put("trustStore", "<PATH_TO_SSO>");
 props.put("trustStoreType", "sso");
```

But it didn't work for me

Update1:
I have tried what user8371915 has suggested and also placed the sso file in both my executor nodes. I am still getting the following exception (abridged version)

```
oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl context.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:325)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:117)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the trust store.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getTrustManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:413)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:309)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: sso not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getTrustManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:401)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: sso KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Hi, is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

First of all (credits go to [Xephi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5242840/xephi) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210194/6910411)) properties are `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType`.

The second problem is that `trustStore` should be accessible on each executor node. Being able to access it from the driver is not enought.