# Not able to connect Oracle with Apache Spark using SSO Wallet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oracle-wallet

We are trying to connect to a remote Oracle database running as AmazonRDS using SSO wallet configured at our end and Apache Spark. We are able to load the data using the `spark-shell` utility as mentioned below

Start the spark shell with jdbc and oraclepki jar added to the classpath

```
 spark-shell --driver-class-path /path/to/ojdbc8.jar:/path/to/oraclepki.jar
```

This is the JDBC url used:

```
 val JDBCURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=www.example.aws.server.com)(PORT=1527))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXX))(SECURITY = (SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN =\"C=US,ST=xxx,L=ZZZ,O=Amazon.com,OU=RDS,CN=www.xxx.aws.zzz.com\")))"
```

And below is the Spark jdbc call to load the data

```
 spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",JDBCURL)
.option("user","USER")
.option("oracle.net.tns_admin","/path/to/tnsnames.ora")
.option("oracle.net.wallet_location","(SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/path/to/ssl_wallet/)))")
.option("password", "password")
.option("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/path/to/cwallet.sso")
.option("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","SSO")
.option("dbtable",QUERY)
.option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").load
```

But when we are trying to run it using the `spark-submit` command we are getting the below error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    ...
    ...
    ...

    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:523)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:521)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
    ... 28 more
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl context.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketEngine(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:597)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:143)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:161)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    ... 33 more
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the key store.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:642)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketEngine(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:580)
    ... 36 more
    Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: SSO not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:628)
    ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSO KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
```

I am very new to spark and might be doing something wrong here. This is how I am trying to configure the Config

```
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(JOB_NAME)
    conf.set("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/cwallet.sso");
    conf.set("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "SSO")
    conf.set("oracle.net.tns_admin", "/path/to/tnsnames.ora")
    conf.set("oracle.net.wallet_location", "(SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/path/to/ssl_wallet/dir/)))")
    conf.set("user", "user")
    conf.set("password", "pass")
```

Below is the `spark-submit` command used

```
    spark-submit --class fully.qualified.path.to.main \
    --jars /path/to/ojdbc8.jar,/path/to/oraclepki.jar,/path/to/osdt_cert.jar,/path/to/osdt_core.jar \
    --deploy-mode client --files /path/to/hive-site.xml --master yarn  \
    --driver-memory 12G \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/cwallet.sso -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=SSO" \
    --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 12G \
    --num-executors 20 /path/to/application.jar /path/to/application_custom_config.conf
```

Also tried to add

`--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/cwallet.sso -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=SSO'`

and

`--files /path/to/cwallet.sso,/path/to/tnsnames.ora`

to the `spark-submit` command but without any luck.
What exactly I am doing wrong here? Also tried the solution mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651557/how-to-specify-trust-store-and-trust-store-type-for-spark-jdbc-connection) but getting the same error.Do I need to make sure `trustStore should be accessible on each executor node` ? If that is the case then why the `spark-shell` command is working fine ? Does this mean spark-cli does not include any worker nodes to execute the command ?

Please advice

**UPDATE:**

> It looks like you're using the JDBC driver from 12.1.0.2. Please upgrade to 18.3 which you can download from oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/… Some changes have been made to make the use of wallets easier. -- @Jean de Lavarene

After following the suggested change by @Jean de Lavarene got rid of the initial error but below is what I am getting now

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, example.server.net, executor 2): java.sql.SQLException: PKI classes not found. To use 'connect /' functionality, oraclepki.jar must be in the classpath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getSecretStoreCredentials(PhysicalConnection.java:3058)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.parseUrl(PhysicalConnection.java:2823)
```

When I run this in spark local mode : `--master local[*]` it works fine but failing with `yarn` mode.

I am already using the `--jars` command with comma separated list of jars. What I found is :

1) `--jars` expect the path to be a local one, and then it copies them to the HDFS path 
2) using `file:///` at the beginning is not working 
3) If I do not specify the `--jars` parameter the program is asking for missing JDBC driver class. Once I specify the `ojdbc8.jar` using --jars then the errors go away and start giving the `oraclepki.jar` not found error. I have **NO CLUE** why this is happening.
4) Also tried using `:` as the separator while specifying multiple jars but without any luck

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to resolve the `oraclepki.jar` not found exception by using the

```
    --driver-class-path /path/to/oraclepki.jar:/path/to/osdt_cert.jar:/path/to/others.jar
```

but once we are running into the `--master yarn` mode then the following exception is being shown

```
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the key store.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:617)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:322)
    ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/cwallet.sso (No such file or directory)
```

As per my understanding it looks like when it launching the job from the worker node the `cwallet.sso` file path is not available on those nodes. We tried to specify a HDFS path for the wallet but the utility expects a local path to be provided when creating the wallet.

So do we need to manually copy the wallet file to all worker nodes ? Or is there any better alternatives to achieve this?

Please advice

Comment: I'm guessing this is not related but your example has `trustStoreType` spelled wrong `conf.set("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreTyp", "SSO")`

Comment: It looks like you're using the JDBC driver from 12.1.0.2. Please upgrade to 18.3 which you can download from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/jdbc-ucp-183-5013470.html Some changes have been made to make the use of wallets easier.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene thank you for the suggestion, please see my updated post

Comment: @user2720864 This new exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet" happens because you also need to upgrade the dependent jars: oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar and osdt_cert.jar. They must all be from the same version, which is 18.3.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene I have already done that .. all of them are from 18.3 only. The classnot found exception has been resolved by ading `--driver-class-path` options. Running into new set of errors now as explanied under **UPDATE 2** header.

Comment: @MikePark thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @user2720864 regarding your update #2, yes you will have to make sure that the wallet is available on all nodes or stored on a shared storage.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? We are having the same issue here, no clue how to resolve it. If you found a solution, it would be very helpful, thanks

Comment: @besil yes we did, but the sso file must be present on all worker nodes . I can provide you a code snippet if required.just could not manage to update it here

Comment: it would be very helpful! we are still not figuring it out

Comment: @besil please check the answer , hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Baically this is how we are able to solve it. One important thing to remember here is the `SSO` file must be present on all nodes where Spark will be running (spark's executor node)

```
    val SOURCE_DF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@...full string here")
        .option("oracle.net.wallet_location", "(SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/path/to/sso/dir)))")
        ...
        ...
```

In case you need to pass additional details you can add more `.options` parameters

```
   .option("oracle.net.tns_admin", "oracle/tns/file/path"))
   .option("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "sso")
```

Comment: Thanks! Which user are you using to run the job? opc or spark?

Comment: @besil You can use any user with proper privilege to run it, please let me know if the above solution works for you. I tried to do this without copying the SSO to all nodes but in vain. Please share in case you are able to do that, would be really useful info for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the key store.
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: SSO not found
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSO KeyStore not available
```

***Observations and Notes:***

1. This error says [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load-java.security.KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter-), as opposed to `TrustStore`. But that's likely just misleading terminology and yet, error messages of both the java and oracle classes use the same term.
2. Root CA certs go in `TrustStore`, but if you were using client keys, you would need these `KeyStore` properties:

   ```
   .option("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/path/to/cwallet.sso")
   .option("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","SSO")
   .option("oracle.net.authentication_services","(TCPS)")
   ```

   The [Oracle JDBC SSL manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-0D5B5CBE-A693-41EC-B671-4F2802FEEF49) itself contributes to the terminology confusion since it never even addresses the `TrustStore`:

   > If the oraclepki.jar file is on the CLASSPATH, then the driver can automatically load the Oracle PKI Provider in the following way:
   >
   > ```
   > java –cp oraclepki.jar:ojdbc8.jar –D javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/wallet/cwallet.sso MyApp
   > ```
   >
   > Similarly, for a specified value of the `oracle.net.wallet_location` connection property, the driver can automatically load the Oracle PKI Provider in the following way:
   >
   > ```
   > java –cp .:oraclepki.jar:ojdbc8.jar –D oracle.net.wallet_location=file:/path/to/wallet/cwallet.sso MyApp
   > ```
3. Based on the above alternative, if you just specify the wallet property, you can apparently omit all the `javax.net.ssl` lines?

   ```
   .option("oracle.net.wallet_location", "(SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/path/to/ssl_wallet)))")
   ```
4. As you found, using an Oracle 12.1 client to connect to an Oracle 18+ database is problematic with SSL. Driver incompatibility issues are showing up as obscure errors (even though this old driver is supposedly "[forward compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-926E5324-D89A-4A00-B1AE-975C1089F0EA)".
5. Oracle 12c drivers don't support all the enhanced features in connection strings ([Easy Connect Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-F0A0C45C-C5E9-45B6-AB86-181218D348CB)), but some connection properties like `wallet_location` were added in the 19c JDBC driver. So using a fully specified self-contained ezconnect connection URL like that may make things easier.
6. Another option is to [use Java JKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.html#Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.JDBC) TrustStore instead of Oracle Wallets.
7. If you still see issues, use `javax.net.debug=all` to capture tracing details.
8. Always test your connections with `tnsping` and `sqlplus` before testing in pyspark.